# Python selenium optional click link

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I have a selenium that suppose to click on link to download a file when the page is visited,
while not all pages have  this link.

so my problem is to be able to click the link if the page has it, while if not there proceed to do some other tasks.

my problem is on pages that doesnt have the link it causes the program to halt and crash.
I am looking for a possible way to click on the link and if the link is not there just proceed and do other things.

```
                try:

                    instructions= WebDriverWait(self.driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                        (By.XPATH,"//dl//div[@class='paper_instructions_view']/a")))

                    if instructions:
                        instructions.click
                    pass

                finally:
                    enter_amount = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='id_bid']")
                    enter_amount.send_keys(get_budget)
                    
                    time.sleep(5)

                    apply= WebDriverWait(self.driver,200).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                        (By.XPATH,"//input[@id='apply_order']"))).submit()
                                        
                    
                    self.click_on_order_button_from_inside()
```

Comment: What is the URL you are checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly analyze carefully errors thrown by script.
In your example in first line after "finally" you're trying to find element with ID="id_bid", but this code is invoked always, in case of absence of this object you get error.
You just need to move all your actions that could fail(for example all find_element_by...) to try clause.
More about try, except, finally:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions

Answer (score 0):

Issue is the way you are handling your exception. As in first answer it is indication irrespective of either button is present or not your final block will always get executed. Assuming you are checking for  `instructions` link on page. You can do below:

```
try:
    instructions= WebDriverWait(self.driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                       (By.XPATH,"//dl//div[@class='paper_instructions_view']/a"))).click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
```

Above code will look for `instructions link` , if its found it will be clicked otherwise it will just `pass`.